# How to generate a bunch of Fake Users into MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a Site that allows users to create a profile and have their own profile page, I want to generate a bunch of fake users to test my site, I have all the details stored into a MySQL Database and was wondering how I would add a random bunch of users to it without having to go to the registration form over and over again!

Here's a screenshot of my current database layout (Field Names)

---

Table Name is user

### [image]

I have seen [randomuser.me](https://randomuser.me/)'s API but since I am no good with JSON, I'd have no idea where to start on this! I have also seen [generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com/) but again, have no Idea how that works!

Comment: What have you tried ? What is holding you from doing this by yourself with simple basic code ?

Comment: I have tried the basic INSERT but this was becoming tedious as I had to repeat the lines of code and add the data in manually. But thanks to another answer, I've manged to complete this now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a procedure like this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myfill()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 1000; -- number of users to be generated ..
  DECLARE txt varchar(8);
  SET txt=v1;
  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    insert INTO user (user_email,user_password,user_firstname,
    user_lastname,user_avatar,user_username,
    user_backgroundpicture,user_joindate) 
    VALUES (concat('mail',txt,'@domain.com'), concat('pwd',txt),
     concat('first',txt),concat('last',txt),concat('avatar',txt),
     concat('user',txt),concat('bg',txt),now() ); 
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
    SET txt=v1;
  END WHILE;
END//
call myfill();
```

See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adf23/1